# tableAdapter, параметризованный sql запрос

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, datagridview, ms-access

Как можно передать количество параметров, которое может каждый раз меняться в sql запрос? Мне нужно следующий запрос оформить для всевозможного количества параметров:
`SELELT * FROM table WHERE name IN (value1, value2, value3, value4)`

Т.е. не обязательно только 4 значения, их может быть и 10, и одно, и каждый раз их количество будет меняться. Я могу собрать строку, как вариант, с нужными значениями, но как ее потом передать в параметризованный запрос? В самом коде применяю все запросы к элементу datagridview через tableAdapter:
`this.запрос_продуктовTableAdapter.Fill(...);`

п.с. Пишу в VS 15 на C#, БД подключал через элемент datagridview, сама БД представляет собой локальный файл .mdb, запросы пишу через мастера настройки запроса.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте создать лист параметров и сгенерировать текст запроса:

```
   List<string> sqlParams = new List<string>();
    sqlParams.Add("value1");
    sqlParams.Add("value2");
    sqlParams.Add("value3");
    sqlParams.Add("value4");
    sqlParams.Add("value5");

    var sqlCommandText = string.Format("SELELT * FROM table WHERE name IN ({0})", string.Join(",", sqlParams));
    MessageBox.Show(sqlCommandText);
```

Нужно еще учитывать тип параметра, для строкового нужно еще добавить ' -
 "'value1'".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(name, @parameter);
```

Т.е. параметр один, а в нём сколько угодно проверяемых значений через запятую. Тип параметра @parameter - строковый, кавычек и прочей ерунды не требуется, проверка выполняется на точное совпадение, т.е. всякие ведущие и замыкающие пробелы являются значимыми.

PS. Если в поле `name` возможно наличие запятой, способ неприменим. Квотирование тут не работает.

Comment: это ж MySQL конструкция?

Comment: Жалуется на неопределенную функцию `FIND_IN_SET`

Comment: Ну если автор озаботится указанием диалекта сервера... а коли нет - то ему, вероятно, для хоть какого-нибудь...

Comment: Локальный сервер, локальный аксессовский файл с бд, я только второй день изучаю связку sql с c#

Comment: Для MS Access вместо `FIND_IN_SET()` по той же методе подойдёт простейший `INSTR()`... только в качестве разделителя придётся подобрать символ, который гарантированно не встречается в данных и в строке поиска. Скажем. `CHR(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
public static void Select(String connectionString, List<Int32> sqlParams)
{
    using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = string.Format($"SELELT * FROM table WHERE name IN (@sqlParams)");
            command.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
            {
                new OleDbParameter("@sqlParams", sqlParams)
            });
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```